# keep HTML as text with JadeJS

Tags: pug

I have this in a `jade` file

```
h2 HTML Before:
code#before <div id="message"><p>New content will go here</p></div>
```

I want to render the `<div>` tag as text to display on a webpage like this:

```
HTML Before:
<div id="message"><p>New content will go here</p></div>  //as text!
```

Any suggestions on how to keep the text from becoming HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
code#before #{'<div id="message"><p>New content will go here</p></div>'}
```

from https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#tag-text